# change from bash shell prompt to regular shell prompt on centos

Tags: linux, bash, shell, boot

my centos environment has just become bash shell prompt:

```
-bash-3.2#
```

how do I change it back to the usual # prompt?  what places should I check for possibly modifications?

Update:
I was not clear in my question:  the prompt used to be just a single # and supports more syntax(a different shell script than bash 3.2 perhaps)? I would like to switch back to that.  for example, ll is not longer supported in this bash shell

Comment: Undo whatever you did that changed it?

Answer (score 2):

set the PS1 environment variable, for more details:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html

After your update: maybe there is an error while you enter terminal and load user scripts?
try:

```
su - yourusername
```

and see if there is an error than.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your bash prompt in ~/.bashrc or if you want to do it globally in /etc/bash.bashrc

You mention 'the usual # prompt', but I'm assuming it doesn't always just show #. If you do want it to ever just show #, just setting "PS1='#'" in your bashrc would be sufficient. If you want more information on the prompt, I would suggest reading http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/CustomizeBash or the more in depth http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/ .